# How to connect to Kafka cluster with Kerberos Authentication on Windows using the Cofluent library?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, apache-kafka, kerberos

I'm working on a project which requires me to connect to an existing Kafka cluster using dotnet and the Confluent library. The Kafka cluster uses Kerberous/Keytab authentication. Looking at some of the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_gssapi.html) it looks like you can pass through the keytab file using the JAAS configuration, but when I look at the properties for the ProudcerConfig in Confluent I don't see anything about authentication. So how do I specify the keytab file so that I can authenticate against the Kafka cluster?

Answer (score 3):

I think [this section of Confluent docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_gssapi.html#clients) mentions how to configure clients:

In your `client.properties` file you'd need the following configuration:

```
sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
# Configure SASL_SSL if SSL encryption is enabled, otherwise configure SASL_PLAINTEXT
security.protocol=SASL_SSL

sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka

sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required \
    useKeyTab=true \
    storeKey=true \
    keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/kafka_client.keytab" \
    principal="kafkaclient1@EXAMPLE.COM";

# optionally - kafka-console-consumer or kafka-console-producer, kinit can be used along with useTicketCache=true
sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required \
   useTicketCache=true;
```

In order to pass `client.properties` to e.g. `kafka-console-consumer` you need to provide `--consumer.config` parameter as well:

For Linux:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test  --consumer.config client.properties --from-beginning
```

For Windows:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --consumer.config client.properties --from-beginning
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I pass in the client.properties when calling kafka-console-consumer.bat from Windows command line?

Comment: Thanks again. I'm now getting a different error, but it seems like it's at least connecting now. The error I receive is "Could not login: the client is being asked for a password, but the Kafka client code does not currently support obtaining a password from the user. not available to garner  authentication information from the user". I shouldn't have to pass to supply a password if I'm using the keytab file though, correct?

Comment: @ajtatum Maybe it's better to ask a new question about the new problem and provide more details about the kerberos configuration.

Comment: What should the value of `keyTab="..."` be on Windows?  Just `C:\whatever\path\myfile.keytab`?   That doesn't work for me...I can't seem to get it to find my keytab.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Try `C:\\whatever\\path\\myfile.keytab`

Comment: Found out it needs to be `keyTab='C:/whatever/path/myfile.keytab'` on Windows--strange, but it needs single-quotes and forward slashes.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Yes. You can either use `C:/whatever/path/myfile.keytab` or `C:\\whatever\\path\\myfile.keytab`. Both of them should work.